# How to delete local and remote repositories in bitbucket using command line in windows OS?

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I am trying delete local and remote repositories in bitbucket using git bash.

I am able to delete my local repository using .git directory in myroot-directory of my repository, but

```
    git remote rm repositoryURL
```

used to delete remote report but i could not.

Can you please help me
Thanks

Comment: You can't create a repository in bitbucket using the git command line, why do you think you can delete one?

Comment: I have clone the my repository using git clone URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few problems here.

> ```
> git remote rm repositoryURL
> ```
>
> used to delete remote report but i could not.

First, [`git remote rm` is used with the *`name`* of the remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), not its *URL*. You'd have to do something like `git remote rm origin`.

This updated command won't work because you have already deleted `.git/`, so you no longer have a local  repository. `git remote` requires a local repository.

But even if you'd run `git remote rm` before deleting `.git/` it wouldn't remove the repository on Bitbucket. The documentation says that `git remote rm <name>`

> Remove the remote named `<name>`. All remote-tracking branches and configuration settings for the remote are removed.

This simply configures your local copy to forget everything it knows about the remote. The repo on Bitbucket will still exist, e.g., you could clone it again.

To actually remove the repository from Bitbucket you have to log into its web interface and do it there (or possibly use the [API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html)).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Now it's deleted